# highchart cannot addSeries

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using HighChart, I am trying to add a data series, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am getting an error.
`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addSeries' of undefined"`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'target_div'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Existing',
                data: [0,0,0]
            }]
        });
    });

    chart.addSeries(
      {
       name: 'Test',
       data: [1,2,3]
      }
    )
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='target_div'>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

---

This worked!

```
$(chart).ready(function() {
  chart.addSeries(
    {
      name: 'test',
      data: [1,2,3]
    }
  )
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `chart.addSeries` inside `$(document).ready`.

When it's getting executed `chart` isn't an instance of `Highcharts`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xAYn6/)

Comment: Yes, you can add a callback to `load` event, which will be a function that is executed after your chart gets loaded.